# docker wordpress + nginx returning empty response on curl without headers

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, curl

I have a wordpress+nginx in a docker container that is working perfectly through the browser, but when I try to send an http request via curl without headers the response is always empty

```
❯ curl -vv localhost:8080
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
```

It does work if I add any User-agent header with the -H option, but I would like it to work even when there's no user-agent in the headers.

Here are my nginx settings:

- nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;
daemon off;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    root /var/www/html;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /dev/stdout main;
    error_log /dev/stderr error;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    #keepalive low (5seconds), should force hackers to re-connect.
    keepalive_timeout  5;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k; 
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;

    #php max upload limit cannot be larger than this
    client_max_body_size 40m;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript image/svg+xml;

    limit_req_zone $remote_addr zone=loginauth:10m rate=15r/s;

    include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include  /etc/nginx/nginx-server.conf;
}
```

- nginx-server.conf

```
server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name "localhost";

    access_log /dev/stdout main;
    error_log /dev/stdout error;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/home/www-data/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    #Deny access to .htaccess, .htpasswd...
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }


    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf|doc|docx|odt|rtf|ppt|pptx|xls|xlsx|txt)$ {
      expires max;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    #Block bad-bots
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (360Spider|80legs.com|Abonti|AcoonBot|Acunetix|adbeat_bot|AddThis.com|adidxbot|ADmantX|AhrefsBot|AngloINFO|Antelope|Applebot|BaiduSpider|BeetleBot|billigerbot|binlar|bitlybot|BlackWidow|BLP_bbot|BoardReader|Bolt\ 0|BOT\ for\ JCE|Bot\ mailto\:craftbot@yahoo\.com|casper|CazoodleBot|CCBot|checkprivacy|ChinaClaw|chromeframe|Clerkbot|Cliqzbot|clshttp|CommonCrawler|comodo|CPython|crawler4j|Crawlera|CRAZYWEBCRAWLER|Curious|Curl|Custo|CWS_proxy|Default\ Browser\ 0|diavol|DigExt|Digincore|DIIbot|discobot|DISCo|DoCoMo|DotBot|Download\ Demon|DTS.Agent|EasouSpider|eCatch|ecxi|EirGrabber|Elmer|EmailCollector|EmailSiphon|EmailWolf|Exabot|ExaleadCloudView|ExpertSearchSpider|ExpertSearch|Express\ WebPictures|ExtractorPro|extract|EyeNetIE|Ezooms|F2S|FastSeek|feedfinder|FeedlyBot|FHscan|finbot|Flamingo_SearchEngine|FlappyBot|FlashGet|flicky|Flipboard|g00g1e|Genieo|genieo|GetRight|GetWeb\!|GigablastOpenSource|GozaikBot|Go\!Zilla|Go\-Ahead\-Got\-It|GrabNet|grab|Grafula|GrapeshotCrawler|GTB5|GT\:\:WWW|Guzzle|harvest|heritrix|HMView|HomePageBot|HTTP\:\:Lite|HTTrack|HubSpot|ia_archiver|icarus6|IDBot|id\-search|IlseBot|Image\ Stripper|Image\ Sucker|Indigonet|Indy\ Library|integromedb|InterGET|InternetSeer\.com|Internet\ Ninja|IRLbot|ISC\ Systems\ iRc\ Search\ 2\.1|jakarta|Java|JetCar|JobdiggerSpider|JOC\ Web\ Spider|Jooblebot|kanagawa|KINGSpider|kmccrew|larbin|LeechFTP|libwww|Lingewoud|LinkChecker|linkdexbot|LinksCrawler|LinksManager\.com_bot|linkwalker|LinqiaRSSBot|LivelapBot|ltx71|LubbersBot|lwp\-trivial|Mail.RU_Bot|masscan|Mass\ Downloader|maverick|Maxthon$|Mediatoolkitbot|MegaIndex|MegaIndex|megaindex|MFC_Tear_Sample|Microsoft\ URL\ Control|microsoft\.url|MIDown\ tool|miner|Missigua\ Locator|Mister\ PiX|mj12bot|Mozilla.*Indy|Mozilla.*NEWT|MSFrontPage|msnbot|Navroad|NearSite|NetAnts|netEstate|NetSpider|NetZIP|Net\ Vampire|NextGenSearchBot|nutch|Octopus|Offline\ Explorer|Offline\ Navigator|OpenindexSpider|OpenWebSpider|OrangeBot|Owlin|PageGrabber|PagesInventory|panopta|panscient\.com|Papa\ Foto|pavuk|pcBrowser|PECL\:\:HTTP|PeoplePal|Photon|PHPCrawl|planetwork|PleaseCrawl|PNAMAIN.EXE|PodcastPartyBot|prijsbest|proximic|psbot|purebot|pycurl|QuerySeekerSpider|R6_CommentReader|R6_FeedFetcher|RealDownload|ReGet|Riddler|Rippers\ 0|rogerbot|RSSingBot|rv\:1.9.1|RyzeCrawler|SafeSearch|SBIder|Scrapy|Scrapy|Screaming|SeaMonkey$|search.goo.ne.jp|SearchmetricsBot|search_robot|SemrushBot|Semrush|SentiBot|SEOkicks|SeznamBot|ShowyouBot|SightupBot|SISTRIX|sitecheck\.internetseer\.com|siteexplorer.info|SiteSnagger|skygrid|Slackbot|Slurp|SmartDownload|Snoopy|Sogou|Sosospider|spaumbot|Steeler|sucker|SuperBot|Superfeedr|SuperHTTP|SurdotlyBot|Surfbot|tAkeOut|Teleport\ Pro|TinEye-bot|TinEye|Toata\ dragostea\ mea\ pentru\ diavola|Toplistbot|trendictionbot|TurnitinBot|turnit|Twitterbot|URI\:\:Fetch|urllib|Vagabondo|Vagabondo|vikspider|VoidEYE|VoilaBot|WBSearchBot|webalta|WebAuto|WebBandit|WebCollage|WebCopier|WebFetch|WebGo\ IS|WebLeacher|WebReaper|WebSauger|Website\ eXtractor|Website\ Quester|WebStripper|WebWhacker|WebZIP|Web\ Image\ Collector|Web\ Sucker|Wells\ Search\ II|WEP\ Search|WeSEE|Wget|Widow|WinInet|woobot|woopingbot|worldwebheritage.org|Wotbox|WPScan|WWWOFFLE|WWW\-Mechanize|Xaldon\ WebSpider|XoviBot|yacybot|Yahoo|YandexBot|Yandex|YisouSpider|zermelo|Zeus|zh-CN|ZmEu|ZumBot|ZyBorg) ) {
              return 444;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/nginx-locations.conf;
    include /var/www/nginx/locations/*;
}
```

- nginx-locations.conf

```
# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory for the single site
location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

#Deny access to wp-content folders for suspicious files
location ~* ^/(wp-content)/(.*?)\.(zip|gz|tar|bzip2|7z)\$ { deny all; }
location ~ ^/wp-content/uploads/sucuri { deny all; }
location ~ ^/wp-content/updraft { deny all; }
location ~* ^/wp-content/uploads/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php|js|swf)$ {
        deny all;
}

# Block PHP files in includes directory.
location ~* /wp-includes/.*\.php\$ {
  deny all;
}

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
# Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
# Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
location ~* /(?:uploads|files|wp-content|wp-includes)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

# Block nginx-help log from public viewing
location ~* /wp-content/uploads/nginx-helper/ { deny all; }

# Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
# Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php\$ { deny all; }

# Deny access to uploads that aren’t images, videos, music, etc.
location ~* ^/wp-content/uploads/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php|js|swf|css)$ {
    deny all;
}



location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
        # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                index  index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# More ideas from:
# https://gist.github.com/ethanpil/1bfd01a817a8198369efec5c4cde6628

location ~* /(\.|wp-config\.php|wp-config\.txt|changelog\.txt|readme\.txt|readme\.html|license\.txt) { deny all; }

# Make sure files with the following extensions do not get loaded by nginx because nginx would display the source code, and these files can contain PASSWORDS!
location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)\$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)\$|\.php_
{
    return 444;
}
#nocgi
location ~* \.(pl|cgi|py|sh|lua)\$ {
    return 444;
}
#disallow
location ~* (w00tw00t) {
    return 444;
}
```

My aim is to get the server to respond to any request, even if it has no User-agent header.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with docker or wordpress or something else.
 It is your nginx-configuration solely that rejecting the request:

You have `Curl` in your http-agent comparison in `nginx-server.conf`:

```
    #Block bad-bots
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (...|Curl|...) ) {
              return 444;
    }
```

and because `~*` is a [case-insensitive matching operator](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if), every request from curl would return with 444 here.

Example how you can check it using grep:

```
$ echo 'curl/7.64.1' | grep -iPo '(...some...|Curl|...other...)'
curl
```

And [code `444` is a special nginx’s non-standard code](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names), which when returned would force nginx to close the connection immediately without to send anything to the client. This is comparable to connection reject (closed by peer).

FWIW: *(for people searching why the request is not processed as expected)* - nginx has a possibility to set `debug` for logging (e. g. can be set for certain port-listener in order to debug it), so an error-log would contain detailed information how the request is processed (which locations and rewrite rules are triggered and what happens with the request on every event stage and what the response and error code will be supplied to client at end).

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for missing such an obvious source of the problem, when I had been looking over everything to try to find the solution before asking here (though not thouroughly enough it seems). Always learning